# how to use preventdefault of jquery in code to prevent repeatation of key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello sir i am developing code in which it is required to keep cursor at the end of text but this code resulting repeatation of key........
my code is

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.focusTextToEnd = function() {
    this.focus();
    var $thisVal = this.val();
    this.val('').val($thisVal);
    return this;

  }
}(jQuery));

('#typing_box').click(focusTextToEnd());
document.getElementById("typing_box").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});


function moveToEnd() {
  $('#typing_box').focusTextToEnd();
}

function validateText() {

  $('#typing_box').focusTextToEnd();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class=typing_area onkeyup="validateText()" style="float: left" id="typing_box" onclick="moveToEnd()"></textarea>
```

what can i do to stop repetation of key in text writing in unicode.

Comment: `('#typing_box')` should be `$('#typing_box')` and `focusTextToEnd()` should probably be `$.fn.focusTextToEnd`

Comment: it is still not working...there is repeatation.

Comment: The repetation started after  using click event

Comment: please any one help me....